# How and when does variable inside function get destroyed?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have successfully implemented a function but unable to exactly grasp the concept, could some please guide.

Suppose I have created a function when server starts,

**server.js:**

```
const bookRefs = ["123","345","121"]

bookRefs.forEach(e=>{
    schedulerFunc(e)
})
```

schedulerFunc is in **controller.js:**

```
exports.schedulerFunc = async (bookRef) => {
    const bookDetails = await Book.find({ book_ref: bookRef }).exec()
    console.log(bookDetails) => [{"bookName":"Hobbit","author":"RR 
Tolkein"},{"bookName":"Harry potter","author":"JK Rowling"}]
    for (let i = 0; i < bookDetails.length; i++) {
            schedule.scheduleJob('*****'//for everyminute, async () => {
                console.log(bookDetails[i].bookname)
            }
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine but what I don't understand, when the server starts it calls schedulerFunc(e) for each bookRefs, and after that scheduleJob is called and for first time it works like it should, and prints the book's name like it should but after 5 min scheduleJob is again triggered and it prints the book's name even though this time we are not fetching bookDetails, it has only been fetched once and scheduleJob is able to print book's name again and again. Why doesn't it throw error **bookDetails[i].bookname** not found?

Let me know if anyone needs more details.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your second to last paragraph.  It would help if you illustrate with actual code and then refer to specific lines of code or `console.log()` statements that you're asking about.  Questions here do a lot better if you're asking about actual code that is included in the question.  Pseudo-code or such small snippets that we can't see what you're really asking about don't work that well here.

Comment: So sorry about that....I will edit my question.

Comment: Still waiting for you to add your actual code, but conceptually a variable in Javascript lasts for as long as there is some live code that can still reference it.  The garbage collector searches for variables that are no longer reachable by operable code and then cleans them up then.

Comment: Sorry I had to run some errands.....I have edited the question please have look.....so until and unless I terminate the function that has actually been triggered the variable will exist and not get destroyed?

P.S.: Thank you for taking your time to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as one or more of your `scheduleJob()` function invocations is still waiting to call its callback, then everything in the scope of that callback is still reachable by the code in the callback so anything that the code in that callback references will be kept alive and will not be cleaned up by the garbage collector until the `scheduleJob()` callback is done and can no longer be called again.

You will note that this situation (referred to as a closure) happens because the callback is declared inline and thus its code can see and reference the variables in the parent scope.  If the callback was not declared inline and was just passed as a reference to an external function definition, then it wouldn't have any access to the variables in the parent scope and they could be garbage collected as soon as the `for` loop is done.

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't understand what you meant by callback is declared inline...does it mean it is inside the function that was triggered on start? Also could you please provide me with some\ document that I can refer to?

Comment: @SivaPradhan - There are a [lot of articles](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+does+garbage+collection+in+javascript+work) about the garbage collector in Javascript if you want further info about how it works.

Comment: @SivaPradhan - Yes, it means the callback function body is inside the function scope which means it can directly access the variables in the parent function.  This is referred to as "lexical scope" if you want to read more about that concept.  If the function body of the callback was declared externally and the callback was just passed as the function name, then that callback function would not have access to the variables in the parent function.